# What does the area of the figure formed by the implicit function $x^{n}+y^{n}=c$ approach as n approaches infinity?

Tags: integration, limits, analytic-geometry, area, implicit-function

What is the area of the figure formed by the implicit function $x^{n} + y^{n} = c$ approach as $n$ approaches $\infty$? ($n$ is an even positive integer)

Of course, the area will likely be a function of $c$.

Was just wondering, no special reason.

Comment: There are a number of free graphing software tools available on the internet. Is there any reason you didn't try plotting them to see for yourself?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} 4 \times \int_{0}^{c^{(1/n)}} f(x) dx.$$
The factor of $(4)$ accommodates that the integral represents the area in the 1st quadrant only.  The upper bound for $x$ is clearly $c^{(1/n)}.$  $f(x)$ represents the (positive) $(y)$ value which is calculated as $$y = \left[c - x^n\right]^{(1/n)}.$$

Comment: @Community  "As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking" : 
**No**, it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area $A$ can be written as,

$$A = \lim_{n \to \infty} 4\int_0^\sqrt[n]{c} \sqrt[n]{c-x^n}dx$$

Since $\sqrt[n]{c-x^n}$ achieves its maximum at $x=0$, we can bound it above,

$$A \le \lim_{n \to \infty} 4\int_0^\sqrt[n]{c} \sqrt[n]{c}dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} 4 c^{\frac 2 n} = 4$$

Maybe with some more work it can be shown that there's a simple lower bound that proves the limit is $4$.

Perhaps surprisingly this implies the area doesn't depend on $c$. If you wanted the area to be dependent on $c$, you could look at $x^n+y^n=c^n$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Playing with n=100,101 taking c=1 in an assumed equation of better physical dimension on Wolfram Alpha...

$$ x^n+y^n= c^n $$

[image]

So can you draw the such graphs for lower values of $n$ say $(7,8)$ and conclude the link between sharp vertex shape and larger $n$?

Ok, what is your experience with area integral for large  $n$?